# How to read all category SMSs in xiaomi lollipop phones

Tags: android, sms, telephony

API provided by android i.e Uri "content://sms/" is giving only default SMS category. It is not giving SMS under Notifications and Blocked category. Do they have provided any other API for these type of SMSs

My device model is Mi 4i.

Comment: Hey, I am looking for the same. I searched a lot and found nothing.